# get values from AlterDialog from 2 numberpickers and edittext

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, numberpicker

I want to make timer with 2 numberpickers to choose the start time by the user and editText to enter the timer name. I have used custom AlterDialog for this. 
What I have problem with is to pass numberpickers results and name entered by the user back to MainActivity fields. 
I should appreciate your support as I try to learn coding by my own.
This is MyDialog.java which opens from MainActivity.

```
LayoutInflater inflater;
View v;
NumberPicker hourPicker;
NumberPicker minPicker;
EditText enterdish; 
TextView yourdishname;

@Override
@NonNull
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_dialog, null);

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setView(v);

        hourPicker = (NumberPicker) v.findViewById(R.id.picker1_hours);
        hourPicker.setMaxValue(36);
        hourPicker.setMinValue(0);
        hourPicker.setWrapSelectorWheel(false);
        hourPicker.setOnValueChangedListener( new NumberPicker.
                OnValueChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int
                    oldVal, int newVal) {

     }
          });
hourPicker.setFormatter(new NumberPicker.Formatter() {
              @Override
              public String format(int i) {
                   return String.format("%02d", i);
             }
           });

minPicker = (NumberPicker) v.findViewById(R.id.picker2_minutes);
minPicker .setMaxValue(59);
minPicker .setMinValue(1);
minPicker .setWrapSelectorWheel(false);
minPicker .setOnValueChangedListener( new NumberPicker.
        OnValueChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int
            oldVal, int newVal) {

        }
  });
minPicker.setFormatter(new NumberPicker.Formatter() {
      @Override
      public String format(int i) {
           return String.format("%02d", i);
     }
   });

    builder.setView(v).setPositiveButton("OK", new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

    enterdish = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.editText1_dishname);
    yourdishname = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView1_dishnamemain);
            yourdishname.setText(enterdish.getText());
        }
    }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

    return builder.create();
}

}
```

Comment: do you got any error?

Comment: Just pass the activity context to your dialog class.Use that context to call the method which receives data from your alert dialog.

Comment: With this code there is no error but nothing happens. When I was trying to put eg. setText or any solutions I could find I got crashes most of the time unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

To send the result to the MainActivity, there is a pattern which you must follow. Create an interface `OnNumberSet` with a single method `onDialogOk(int value);`. Make your MainActivity implement this interface and override this method and do anything you want with that value, as it will be the value from the NumberPicker.

Now, in the AlertDialog (which I suppose was started from MainActivity):

Declare a global field `OnNumberSet mCallBack;`; Then override the `onAttach` method:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

    // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
    // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception
    try {
        mCallBack= (OnNumberSet) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement onDialogOk");
    }
}
```

After that:
Make your NumberPicker final and declare it in onCreateDialog method:

`final NumberPicker minPicker = (NumberPicker) v.findViewById(R.id.picker2_minutes);`

In your positiveButton onClickListener :

```
builder.setView(v).setPositiveButton("OK", new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        int numberPickerValue = minPicker.getValue();
        mCallBack.onDialogOk(numberPickerValue );
    }
```

If you have your Edittext in the same dialog, declare the EditText, find its view, make it final, and in the same onClick method from positive button, call `String text = editText.getText()`. In this case, you also must add a String parameter to the `onDialogOk` method... Obs. The dialog should extend DialogFragment